# Como somar todos dados de uma tabela

Tags: php, html, mysql

Tenho a tabela 'pedidos' onde todos os pedidos que foram realizados ficam, gostaria apenas de somar todos os pedidos e mostrar na tela.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No exemplo acima tenho 8 pedidos, na tela simplesmente vai  ter "Quantidade de pedidos realizados 8", se deu pra entender.

```html
    <?php 
        require  'conexao_pedidos.php';
        $sql = query("SELECT order_id FROM orders GROUP BY order_id;");
        $result=$conn->query($sql);
        while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()){
    ?>
    <div class="text-center"><?=  $row ?></div>
    <?php
  }
  ?>
```

Comment: Você quer contar quantos registros tem numa tabela?

Comment: exatamente e mostrar tela.

Comment: Coloque o código que está usando para consultar a tabela. Na prática, é só selecionar tudo que está na tabela e contar quantos itens veio com o `count`.

Comment: Acrescentei na pergunta o código que tenho até o momento.

Answer (score 2):

Para contar o número de registros de uma tabela você tem duas opções, ou por *SQL* usando a função agregada [`COUNT(*)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count) que retorna a contagem do número de linhas recuperadas em uma consulta ou por *PHP* através da propriedade [`num_row`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) do objeto [`mysqli_result`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php)(Acredito ser mysqli pois PDO não possui o método [`fetch_assoc()`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php)).

Por SQL usando `COUNT(*)`:

```
$sql = query("SELECT COUNT(*) as pedidos FROM orders;"); //Aqui eu não entendi o uso do GROUP BY order_id pois order_id parece ser a chave primária da tabela
$row= $conn->query($sql)->fetch_assoc(); // A consulta irá retornar apenas uma linha
echo "Número de pedidos: ".$row['pedidos'];
```

Por PHP usando `mysqli_result::num_rows`:

```
$sql = query("SELECT order_id FROM orders;");
$result= $conn->query($sql);
echo "Número de pedidos: ".$result->num_rows;
```

Comment: Estou fazendo isso e não está me retornando nada em nenhum das duas opções.                         <?php 
        include 'header.php';
        require 'conexao_pedidos';
        $sql = query("SELECT order_id FROM orders;");
$result= $conn->query($sql);
echo "Número de pedidos: ".$result->num_rows;
?>

Comment: O que está sendo retornado?

Comment: nenhum dado, está tudo em branco

Comment: Se fizer essa query `SELECT * FROM orders` qual o resultado?